# Use jQuery to get a class from a DIV and add another class to all DIVs with the first class

Tags: jquery, html, addclass

Basically I have a tabbed Panel I'm creating. When the user click on a tab I want the panel to switch out. The tab has a class identical to a class on the corresponding panel. I want to use jQuery get ($this) class and to say when you click on the tab with XX class add class ".active" to all DIVs with XX class.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="bundle_panel">
    <div class="tab tXX">TITLE_HERE</div>
    <div class="panel tXX">CONTENT_HERE</div>
</div>
```

I've tried this jQuery to no efect:

```
$(".bundle_panel .tab").click(function(){
    var panelClass = $(this).attr("class");
    $(panelClass).addClass('active');
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if I need to clarify anything or give more information.

Comment: what problem are you facing. can you create a sample in jsfiddle?

Comment: Will your tab title divs always have just two classes (e.g. "tab tXX") or could the format in your example change?

Comment: They will only have those two classes until the ".active" class gets added by the jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your example is that the click will result in assigning the value of "tab tXX" to your panelClass variable. Then your line `$(panelClass).addClass('active');` is trying to add the active class to an element that doesn't exit. If you use:

```
$(".bundle_panel .tab").click(function(){
    var panelClass = $(this).attr("class").split(' ');
    $(".panel."+panelClass[1]).addClass('active');
});​
```

this will apply the active class to all elements with the "panel" class and the second class of the element clicked on (using your example code, TXX). **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/FZ9aw/)**.

Comment: This is great! thanks! However, when I put it in my code nothing happens. I'm stumped. It looks exactly like the JS Fiddle. :( I even tried something simple and just tried to addClass to the tab on click. Here's the link. Any suggestions? http://dev.thesafetyjunction.com/family-peparedness-pack/

Comment: It's not conflicting with any code and I am using the 1.7.2 library.

Comment: I am using PHP to bring in the class names. Could it be that maybe?

Comment: Try placing the code at the top of your jQuery block, after the document.ready. I copied your code and ran it locally and that seemed to fix the issue of it not running (it wasn't in the right spot). Now though you'll probably want to work on removing the active class from all your other tabs.

Comment: That worked. I had tried that earlier and it didn't but I cleared my cache this time and it executed just fine. THANKS! :) Yeah, I knew after this step I would have to clear active tabs, but that won't be an issue now. Again, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

A much better way to implement tabs is to use an `id` attribute for each "panel" and link to those `id`s from your tabs:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#panel-1">Panel 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#panel-2">Panel 2</a></li>
</ul>

<section id="panel-1">
    <h2>Panel 1</h2>
    <p>Content</p>
</section>

<section id="panel-2">
    <h2>Panel 2</h2>
    <p>Content</p>
</section>
```

Then you can simply:

```
$('ul.tabs a').click(function () {
    var target = $(this).attr('href');

    $(target).show();
});
```

Edit: the added benefit is that it makes sense without JavaScript as well.

Edit2: In your code the problem was that you were trying to select *only* the class name, without prefixing it with a dot (.), it should be:

```
$('.' + panelClass).addClass('active');
```